# How do i grant write-permission to a java-program?

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, java

I wrote a Java program, which should change my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy file. I have a server, which is not always running and i don't want to manually change the proxy, so i made a graphical program.

Everything is working, however, only if i change the directory-owner to me instead of root, and i don't like this... Is there a way to grant superuser write-permission to my java-program?

For example that the window asking for the password is popping up, but not when i start the program, only when i click on the button to change the proxy.

the program does the following:

- look if server is up (working, without su)
- look if proxy is set to server (working, without su)
- set proxy to server / normal (working, only with su)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should ever grant superuser access to anything.

I suggest to copy `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy` to a location that is writable by your java program, and then symlink to it from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy`. Like this:

```
cp /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy ~/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
sudo ln -sf ~/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
```

Comment: thx, works great :)